# How To Make Link on Parent Node Active in Tree View?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make link on parent node active in tree view. So far I do this:

```
<li><a href="beranda">A - Referensi Spasial</a> <!--this is parent node-->
    <ul>
        <li>Jaring Kerangka Referensi Geodesi</li>
        <li>Model Geoid
            <ul>
                <li><a href="kugi/detail_data_kugi">AB01010010</a></li>
                <li>AB01010020</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Stasiun Pasang Surut</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I click the parent node, it just expand the children nodes. What I want is when I click it, it open the link I set on `<a></a>`

Here is my screenshot of my tree view:

[image: tree view]

And this is the javascript code:

```
    $.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

        var openedClass = 'glyphicon-minus-sign';
        var closedClass = 'glyphicon-plus-sign';

        if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
                openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
                closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
        };

        //initialize each of the top levels
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
            var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
            branch.prepend("<i class='indicator glyphicon " + closedClass + "'></i>");
            branch.addClass('branch');
            branch.on('click', function (e) {
                if (this == e.target) {
                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                    icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                    $(this).children().children().toggle();
                }
            })
            branch.children().children().toggle();
        });
        //fire event from the dynamically added icon
        tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews
    $('#tree1').treed();
```

So, how can I do that thing? Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you are asking why your links seem to have no effect at all, and clicking on them just expands the tree as if it were normal text?

It seems to me that this is simply due to the code that attaches events on those links, i.e. the block below comment *"fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text"*.

The `$(this).closest('li').click();` instruction generates a new click event on the parent "li" item.

The `e.preventDefault();` instruction prevents the link from receiving the "click" event, therefore it does not redirect the page / scroll to anchor.

So the result is as if the "click" had "jumped" your link and be passed to the parent "li", therefore not redirecting but expanding the tree.

You could simply remove that block to restore the links normal behaviour. However, the "click" event would still bubble to the parent "li" element, and expand the tree. Not an issue if the pages is redirected, but it is noticeable if the link goes to a local anchor (same page).

To prevent this (but still let the link do its normal job), keep the block but replace the 2 inner instructions by `e.stopPropagation();`. On the contrary of `preventDefault()`, it lets the current event happening, but it stops the event bubbling (parent elements do not receive it).

Now I am not sure about the reason for that block. It seems that it was more intended for anchors (which use the same "a" tag but with "name" attribute instead of "href"). But there would be no reason to prevent the "click" event on an anchor?

Comment: Well, that simple changes made a lot impact. It works for me. Thanks